# Mysql update count of records

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'product_records' as follows:

> ```
> id - int (6),
> product_group - int (7),
> product_subgroup - int (7),
> type - int(3),
> count_of_reports - int (6)
> ```

At the moment the values in column count_of_reports for all records are 0.

What is the most efficient way of adding count_of_reports for every row for matching  product_group, product_subgroup and type?

Example:

```
1, 23, 1, 1, count here (i.e. 2); 
2, 23, 2, 1, count here (i.e. 1);
3, 23, 1, 1, count here (i.e. 2); 
4, 24, 1, 3, count here (i.e. 1);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use an `UPDATE` statement containing a `JOIN` with a subquery that calculates the count for each group.

Comment: Whether it's efficient will depend on whether you index the columns being used for grouping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below update statement -

```
UPDATE product_records PR
JOIN (SELECT CONCAT(product_group, product_subgroup) ID, COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(product_group, product_subgroup)) NUM
      FROM product_records
      GROUP  BY CONCAT(product_group, product_subgroup)) PR2
ON CONCAT(PR.product_group, PR.product_subgroup) = PR2.ID
SET PR.count_of_reports = PR2.NUM
```